# SQL Error during Spring boot start for creating table for H2

Tags: sql, h2

Following is the SQL to create a table:

```
create table if not exists Product (
id int identity(1, 1),
name varchar(50) not null,
price float (7, 2) not null,
description varchar(100) not null);
```

It gives error while its executed during Spring boot start:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCT ( ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, PRICE FLOAT (7,[*] 2) NOT NULL, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL )"; expected ")";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an incorrect column data type definition. `FLOAT` data type has only one parameter: the minimal required binary precision (in bits). This data type is also an approximate precision data type and can't be used for currency values.

You need to use the `NUMERIC (7, 2)` data type instead.